# Por que mysqli_ é melhor que mysql_?

Tags: php, mysqli

Gostaria de saber quais são as vantagens que `mysqli_` possui em relação a `mysql_`, pois ficam me sugerindo direto passar para `mysqli_`.

Comment: O primeiro motivo é simples e óbvio. O php_mysqli é a versão aprimorada do php_mysql. A library php_mysql está obsoleta desde a versão 5.5. 
A recomendação para mudança vem sendo amplamente divulgada há mais 6 anos.

Comment: Tá complicado lidar com as duplicadas ultimamente. A pessoa pergunta sem pesquisar, as pessoas respondem sem pesquisar, aí o AP aceita logo alguma, mesmo que não tenha qualidade já encontrada no site, antes que fechem.

Comment: ver um código utilizando mysql_ ou mysqli_ é no mínimo nostálgico pra mim.

Comment: @bigown por acaso eu pesquisei bastante até, mas não encontrei essa pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funções `MySQL` são depreciadas, portanto, funções `MySQLi` acabam sendo mais novas, seguras, possuem novas features(funcionalidades) e são orientadas a  objetos. Fora que `MySQLi` é uma evolução do `MySQL`.

Ainda há uma alternativa do `MySQLi` que é o `PDO` (driver que implementa a interface PHP Data Objects) que permite trabalhar com múltiplos bancos de dados de forma transparente.

Comment: Prefiro PDO ^_^

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Também =D

Answer (score 3):

Acho que não estás com ideia do que é [`mysqli_`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) e [`mysql_`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php). Isso não são SGBD diferentes. São bibliotecas (extensões) de acesso a uma base de dados MySQL através do PHP. A diferença é que as funções do tipo [`mysql_`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) vão ser descontinuadas e apareceram as melhoradas [`mysqli_`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) para substituir.

Comment: Apesar de parecer óbvio, concordo plenamente com sua explicação de "não são SGBD". Para quem está iniciando, isso pode realmente parecer confuso :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se vires a pergunta original percebes que parece que o AP acha que são SGBD.

Comment: @Wallace, o título original, e o contexto, tal como as tags, não incluía PHP. Eu também acho que o AP poderia estar confundindo com SGDB. Na primeira edição eu deixei explícito como php_mysql e php_mysqli, porém, alguém removeu e deixou mysql_ e mysqli_..

Comment: Fui eu @DanielOmnie não ficou melhor assim?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo título colocando no manual sobre a biblioteca `mysqli`, eu respondo de maneira bem simples:

> Por que mysqli_ é melhor que mysql_?

Porque, de acordo com o manual, é:

> Extensão MySQL Melhorada

Veja aqui nesse [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Eu outras palavras: a extensão `Mysqli` é a evolução da extensão `Mysql` para o PHP.

No caso, eu aconselho você deixar os seus códigos com `mysqli`, já que a extensão `mysql` já foi descontinuado (e o seu uso se torna desencorajado pelo pessoal do PHP).

Comment: E o MariaDB e a mesma coisa que Mysqli ?

Comment: Não, é outro SGDB. É tipo a diferença de Postgresql, Mysql, SqlServer, Sqlite e afins :)

Comment: Rodrigo... mysql e mysqli ao qual vc se refere são apenas bibliotecas do PHP para conexão com o SGDB MySQL..

Comment: Quando eu disse "é outro SGDB" eu não quis dizer que Mysqli era um SGDB, e sim o "Maria DB"