# Como faço para não permitir "<" e ">" no meu Insert

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom, eu tenho um INSERT, e gostaria de fazer com que se alguém digitar no texto algo com "<" ou ">" que desse erro ao enviar.

Código:

```
    $autor_id   = $_POST ["autor_id"];  
    $texto  = $_POST ["texto"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `videos` ( `autor_id` , `texto`, `id` ) 
    VALUES ('$autor_id', '$texto', '')";

    mysql_query($query,$conexao);
```

Comment: Poderia me auxiliar em relação a ela?

Comment: Se alguma resposta te ajudou ou resolveu seu problema, dê um voto e marque como a resposta correta, caso contrário, informe mais detalhes sobre o que tentou e os resultados que obteve. Sempre votar e escolher as respostas corretas é uma boa prática e ajuda os outros usuários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefiro utilizar expressões regulares para esse tipo de verificação.

Exemplo:

```
$texto = "Este <é> <um teste >>>para remover<><><><><> caracteres <>";
$resultado = preg_replace("/[<>]/", "", $texto);
echo $resultado;
//Este é um teste para remover caracteres
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de evitar o `<` e `>` você poderia converte-los na hora da leitura (lembre-se no INSERT é melhor manter o original como foi escrito), então no momento que usar SELECT o `<` e `>` serão convertidos para `&lt;` e `&gt;`, assim evitando injetar HTML na página, mas podendo manter o texto o mais próximo do que o autor escreveu.

Outra coisa você deve prevenir não só a "injeção" de HTML, mas também a "injeção" de mysql (ou falhas de sintaxe), use `mysql_real_escape`

```
$autor_id   = mysql_real_escape($_POST["autor_id"]);
$texto  = mysql_real_escape($_POST["texto"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO `videos` ( `autor_id` , `texto`, `id` ) VALUES ('$autor_id', '$texto', '')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);
```

Na leitura use `htmlspecialchars`, exemplo:

```
$query = 'SELECT autor_id, id, texto FROM `videos` LIMIT 30';
$consulta = mysql_query($query, $conexao);

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
     echo 'texto: ', htmlspecialchars($linha['texto']), '<br>';
}
```

---

### Api antiga do Mysql para PHP vs PDO e Mysqli

Como já foi dito algumas vezes no SOpt:

- [Por que mysqli_ é melhor que mysql_?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74851/3635)
- [Como atualizar meu código MySQL para MySQLi?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47880/3635)

A API do php `mysql_` será descontinuada (Não quer dizer que o mysql será descontinuado, apenas a API do PHP) pois ela foi substituída pelo `mysqli_*`, então é altamente recomendável que atualize seus códigos para usar ou `mysqli` ou `pdo`

### Vantagens do mysqli

- Interface de orientação há objetos (Object-oriented interface)
- Suporte para Prepared Statements
- Suporte para múltiplos Statements
- Suporte para transações (Transactions)
- Melhoria no capacidade de depuração
- Suporte para servidor embarcado

### Vantagens do PDO

Como foi dito pelo [@Kazzkiq](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8338/3635):

- **Vantagens:**

  - Funciona com 12 drivers de bancos de dados diferentes (4D, MS SQL Server, Firebird/Interbase, MySQL, Oracle, ODBC/DB2, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Informix, IBM, CUBRID);
  - API Orientada a objetos;
  - Possui parâmetros nomeados;
  - Possui prepared statements do lado cliente (ver desvantagens abaixo)
- **Desvantagens:**

  - Não tão veloz quanto `MySQLi`;
  - Por padrão, ele simula prepared statements (você pode ativar a versão nativa ao configurar a conexão dele com o banco, mas caso a versão nativa não funcione por algum motivo, ele volta a simular os prepared statements **sem disparar erros ou avisos**. [Mais detalhes aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919645/can-i-use-real-prepared-statements-for-mysql-with-pdo-now))

### Por que atualizar seus códigos

Como eu disse nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635), é preciso notar que as funções `mysql_` não recebem mais atualizações, como correções e melhorias e este é o ponto vital para você não usar mais o `mysql_`, pois no futuro breve ele deixará de existir para as novas versões do PHP.

Em outras palavras, se você continuar a funções `mysql_` (sem o `i`), duas situações podem acontecer com seus projetos:

- Podem haver falhas na segurança da API `mysql_` ou bugs.
- Quando a API `mysql_` for desativada, os seus scripts irão parar de funcionar, o que irá lhe causar muita dor de cabeça, pois você terá que refazer vários códigos.

### Como usar mysqli com o seu código

A inserção pode ser assim:

```
$autor_id   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["autor_id"]);
$texto  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["texto"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO `videos` ( `autor_id` , `texto`, `id` ) VALUES ('$autor_id', '$texto', '')";

mysqli_query($query,$conexao);
```

Na leitura use `htmlspecialchars`, exemplo:

```
$query = 'SELECT autor_id, id, texto FROM `videos` LIMIT 30';
$consulta = mysqli_query($query, $conexao);

while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
     echo 'texto: ', htmlspecialchars($linha['texto']), '<br>';
}
```

No entanto você pode usar os **prepared statements**, assim não terá a necessidade de usar `mysqli_real_escape_string`, exemplo de inserção de dados:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }

    $autor_id = $_POST["autor_id"];
    $texto    = $_POST["texto"];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `videos` ( `autor_id` , `texto`, `id` ) VALUES (?, ?, '')")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('i', $autor_id);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $texto);

        $stmt->execute();

        while ($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 'texto: ', htmlspecialchars($linha['texto']), '<br>';
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
```

### Documentação:

- [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar isto:

```
if (strpos($_POST["texto"],'>') !== false || strpos($_POST["texto"],'<') !== false) {

    echo "Foi detetato > ou < no post!";
    die();
}else{
     // Executa sql aqui.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo fazer a verificação tanto no PHP, como já foi respondido, quanto em javascript.

No javascript porque o formulário nem é enviado, não utiliza rede, internet e nem recursos do seu servidor a toa, só o navegador do visitante. O visitante também não perde os dados e você não precisa nenhum esforço para colocar os dados renovo no formulário. No PHP para os espertinhos que passarem pela checagem do javascript, que está lá só para ajudá-los

Para fazer o javascript pode usar a propriedade onsubmit do formulário:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function checaTexto() {
  var strtexto;
  strtexto = document.getElementById("texto").value;  
  if ((strtexto.search("<") != -1) || (strtexto.search(">") != -1)) {
    alert("O texto não pode conter os caracteres '<' e '>'.");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
...
<form id="formid" onsubmit="return checaTexto()" action="pagina.php">
<textarea id="texto" name="texto">
...
```

Há várias outras maneiras de fazer, usar jQuery para atribuir o evento, variável `this` para a referência do formulário, etc. O exemplo é apenas uma das maneiras.

No PHP, como indicou o Hardcoder acho que seria adequado, já que pediu um "erro" ao enviar tais caracteres.